# Big Theta Notation formula is confusing need clarity

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

If the mathematical rule for Big Theta notation is :

```
f(n) = Theta (g(n)) if and only if f(n) >= cg(n) for some c after n >= n0 >=0
```

then when f(n) = 5n<sup>2</sup> then we consider it as Theta(n<sup>2</sup>)

Considering 5n<sup>2</sup> >= n<sup>2</sup> for c = 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 0

But
Why not f(n) = theta(n)

Considering 5n<sup>2</sup> >= n for c = 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 0 ??

Comment: I that case for every value of n0 in N 5n^2 >= n

Comment: Your formula is wrong. Big-O is `<=` and not `>=` (that is Big-Omega).

Comment: Then why not n^2 is O(n)

Comment: `f` is required to be **less than** (or equal) to `g` (asymptotically and with allowed constants). But `n^2` is bigger than `n`. There is no `c` and `n_0` such that `n^2` will be `<=` than `c * n` for all `n > n_0`. It means that you need to find an area from where on `f` is always bigger than `c * g`.

Comment: You can't edit the question until its correct... That makes all previously correct answers invalid. Instead, create a new question. And yes, with `Big-Omega` you have `5n^2 in Omega(n)` and `5n^2 in Omega(n^2)`. But not in bigger sets like `5n^2 not in Omega(n^3)`.

Comment: Thank you Zabuza :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Theta(g)` is a **set** of functions. So technically you need to write `f in Theta(g)` and not `f = Theta(g)`.

Informally `Theta(g)` contains all functions that grow equally strong (asymptotically). So it is like an asymptotical `=` (equal).

Some `f` is in `Theta(g)` iff it is in `O(g)` and `Omega(g)` at once.

---

Now to your example. We have `f(n) = 5n^2`. As you said, it is in `Theta(n^2)` But it is **not** in `Theta(n)`. Your example was `c = 1` and `n_0 = 0`.

At this point your formula is **wrong**. The definition of Big-O is

[image]

So with a `<=` and not with `>=`, that would be Big-Omega.

We get

```
5n^2 <= 1 * n
```

for your values, let's plot it for all `n >= n_0 = 0`:

[image]

As seen, `f` is **not** less than `1 * g` for all `n >= n_0`. Thus, it is not in `O(n)`.

And since `Theta` means both, `O` and `Omega`, you can't be in `Theta` if you are not in `O`.